# Query select multiple many to many relationship table

Tags: jquery, sql, database

[image]

I had a problem query to select data from those relationship tables on same time

```
SELECT posts.title, tags.tag
FROM posts_tags, categories_detail
INNER JOIN posts
ON posts.idpost = posts_tags.idpost, posts.idpost = categories_detail.idpost
INNER JOIN tags
ON tags.idtag = posts_tags.idtag 
INNER JOIN categories
ON categories.idcategory = categories_detail.idcategory
```

I tried that query but it's not working. Here's the error

[image]

Comment: sorry, I already update my question with the code and the error.

Comment: Hi, can you paste the error message instead of the image as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error is due to a `,` in the `ON`:

```
ON posts.idpost = posts_tags.idpost, posts.idpost = categories_detail.idpost
```

You should use `AND` instead.

```
ON posts.idpost = posts_tags.idpost AND posts.idpost = categories_detail.idpost
```

Comment: i change my code like this 

`SELECT posts.title, tags.tag
FROM posts_tags AND categories_detail
INNER JOIN posts
ON posts.idpost = posts_tags.idpost AND posts.idpost = categories_detail.idpost
INNER JOIN tags
ON tags.idtag = posts_tags.idtag 
INNER JOIN categories
ON categories.idcategory = categories_detail.idcategory`

but still not working

Comment: You shouldn't use `AND` in the `FROM`, just in the `ON`. Try this: `SELECT posts.title, tags.tag
FROM posts
INNER JOIN posts_tags
ON posts.idpost = posts_tags.idpost
INNER JOIN tags
ON tags.idtag = posts_tags.idtag
INNER JOIN categories_detail
ON posts.idtag = categories_detail.idpost`

Comment: Actually, try his one, instead, it is more complete: `SELECT posts.title, tags.tag
FROM posts
INNER JOIN posts_tags
ON posts.idpost = posts_tags.idpost
INNER JOIN tags
ON tags.idtag = posts_tags.idtag
INNER JOIN categories_detail
ON posts.idtag = categories_detail.idpost
INNER JOIN categories
ON categories_detail.idcategory = categories.idcategory`

Comment: thanks, it works. I just change `posts.idtag = categories_detail.idpost ` to  `posts.idpost = categories_detail.idpost `

Comment: I still get some issue for this query. I try insert 1 data but it show 2 record     same data

Comment: That's because there will be one line for each tag. That's how SQL joins work.